# Matching only some words in query using Django Haystack

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am currently using the following django-haystack code to do searches on my site:

```
def products_search_results(request):
    q = request.GET['q']
    from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
    products = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(text=q)
```

This uses `q` as the query parameter in the search. This is also using all words in `q` to match the results against. This is probably (?) the intended default behavior. Here is what I am seeing.

I have a `Product` with a title of "Red Corvette".

Of course the search term "Red", "Red Corvette" and "Corvette" all match, but the term "Red Corvette Convertible" or "Red Corvette T-top" will not match. I would really like those to match the query, especially if there are not many results to the default query.

Is there something I can do with my haystack query to get this kind of behavior?

Comment: When I installed Haystack, what you require was the default behavior. Maybe it has been set as the default on the latest Haystack, since your question was from 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EdgeNgramField` for example in your search index file:

```
class AppIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    ngram_text = indexes.EdgeNgramField()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        """Add the content of text field from final prepared data into ngram_text field
        """
        prepared_data = super(AppIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        prepared_data['ngram_text'] = prepared_data['text']
        return prepared_data
```

Then query on that field (Make sure to first do `rebuild_index` and `update_index` after doing above changes):

```
products = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(ngram_text=q)
```